# How do you pull a list of images from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I've managed to successfully upload some photos to firebase but I want to download all the images at a certain location

currently I have to do this ugly code:

```
const getPhotos = async () => {
    var storage = firebaseApp.storage()
    var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://my-app.appspot.com/')
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        await gsReference
            .child(`${user.id}/${name}/photo${i}.jpg`)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
                fetch(url).then((res) => {
                    setPhotos((photos) => photos.concat(res.url))
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('ERROR!', error)
            })
    }
}
```

this relies on all the photos being called `photo1.jpg`, `photo2.jpg` etc.

is there a way to just pull them all regardless of what they're called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is [Reference.listAll](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#listall) function

```js
const getPhotos = async () => {
    const storage = firebaseApp.storage();
    let reference = storage.refFromURL('gs://my-app.appspot.com/');
    reference = reference.child(`${user.id}/${name}`);

    const {items} = await reference.listAll();
    const urlPromises = items.map(pr => pr.getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => fetch(url))
      .catch(error => error));

    let urls = await Promise.all(urlPromises);
    urls = urls.filter(result => !(result instanceof Error));

    setPhotos(urls);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jozef, thanks for this answer was great. was wondering if you could help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149482/how-to-get-a-reference-to-firebase-image-to-be-able-to-delete-it. not sure how to get the reference for each one so I can delete the image