# How to get a reference to firebase image to be able to delete it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

so I have this function to retrieve all my photos

```
const getPhotos = async () => {
    const storage = firebaseApp.storage()
    let gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://my-app/')
    gsReference = gsReference.child(`${id}/${country}`)

    const { items } = await gsReference.listAll()
    const urlPromises = items.map((pr) =>
        pr
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => fetch(url))
            .catch((error) => error),
    )

    let urls = await Promise.all(urlPromises)
    urls = urls.filter((result) => !(result instanceof Error))
    setPhotos(urls)
}
```

this works all good

now the problem is when I want to delete an image. ive got this function

```
const deletePhoto = (photoRef) => {
    console.log('PHOTO:', photoRef)
    var storage = firebaseApp.storage()
    var storageRef = storage.ref(`${id}/${country}`)
}
```

the problem is I have no way of knowing the reference to the image I want to delete?

I am mapping over all the images and for each image I'm attaching the delete function and passing in the photo as an arg. however this just returns me this

```
body: ReadableStream {locked: false}
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {append: function, delete: function, get: function, has: function, set: 
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-app.appspot.com/o/F2DFB6714-8082-4AF9-89…"
```

it looks like the url does reference the path but it cuts some of it off at the end. plus I don't really want to be splicing that down to find the image. there must be an easy way to set the reference??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `Response` and `Reference` object in another `then` callback after `catch`.

```js
const getPhotos = async () => {
    const storage = firebaseApp.storage()
    let gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://my-app/')
    gsReference = gsReference.child(`${id}/${country}`)

    const { items: references } = await gsReference.listAll()
    const result = references.map(async (reference) => {
        const url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
        let response = null;

        try {
           response = await fetch(url);
        }
        catch(error) {
           response = error;
        }

        return {
           response,
           url,
           reference
        }
      }
    )

    let referencesWithUrls = await Promise.all(result)
    referencesWithUrls = referencesWithUrls.filter((result) => !(result.response instanceof Error))
    setPhotos(referencesWithUrls.map(pr => pr.response))
}
```

Comment: so im getting this as undefined: `const { references } = await gsReference.listAll()` so I changed it to `const { items } = await gsReference.listAll()`

which almost worked but I'm getting `id/country` as the reference but I need the image inside that path

Comment: I think we're v close. but in the Reference.location.path is coming back as `randomid/country` when it needs to be `randomid/country.pathtofile.jpg`

Comment: also I can see the correct path when I do this: ` console.log(reference)` inside the map

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I think all your answers are doing the same coz the reference comes back as this: `"randomid123/country"` but it should be `"randomid123/country/image.jpg"` and when I log out at the map I see the correction location but for some reason yours is just giving me the `randomid123/country` reference and not including the filename

Comment: Does [Reference.fullPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#fullpath) get missing firename?

Comment: gets undefined yeh

Comment: I did `fullpath` but doing `fullPath` it is correct

Comment: but I think this line `setPhotos(referencesWithUrls.map((pr) => pr.response))` is causing it to not sent the `reference` through to my state?

Comment: just need to find a way of merging the response with the reference and I can make this as correct!

Comment: something like this: `{ repsonse: pr.response, storRef: pr.reference }` but not that

Comment: looks like I can just do `setPhotos(referencesWithUrls.map((pr) => pr))` and it works! nice one

Comment: You can change that to `setPhotos(referencesWithUrls)` i thought you want to keep the same data structure as before